Is sagging allowed on a pergola or gazebo roof?
I have a 15.75 feet by 19.7 feet root top.  The frame is made of metal.  When the roof was first installed, the builder ran the main beams along the 19.7 feet which I think caused some sagging.  We can see the water build up on the roof top after some raining.
They changed it by running the main beams along the 15.75 feet.
The roof top is plexiglass 10mm thickness.
I can follow up with more details and pictures if interested.
My general question is sagging overtime allowed in such structure?
The builder said that there's an acceptable sagging allowed after time.  I asked for a specific sagging measurement, he said about .8 inch.
If the metal beams are strong enough, why would there be sagging after time.

Usually for metal buildings there are engineer reports.  They should say the amount of sagging(if any) is allowed.  Usually sagging for small buildings/distance is usually caused by too small size of beams for distance/open span or too much weight on top.
